# Moving background animation

Tags: corona-sdk, image-effects

How can I create a moving background animation with corona like in this game?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyXxyApKtvM

it looks like it uses a single image and stretches it in a loop.
I've search over corona docs but can't find anything that would enable me to manipulate an image in such way.

Comment: It looks like that background could be created with a texture placed on a [skybox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_%28video_games%29) or some other mesh and then the UV placement values are slowly changed.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite What is "UV placement"?

Comment: I mean the way the texture is applied to the mesh triangles

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a Scrolling Background. You can follow this tutorial for Corona: http://thatssopanda.com/corona-sdk-tutorials/create-a-scrolling-background-going-up/

It uses at least 2 images that are moved at the same speed, when one of the images goes outside the viewable area, it is moved to the other side of the screen to create that "continuous scrolling effect"

Hope it helps

Comment: no! it's completely different.